# Azure PowerShell blob download - to confirm No always

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a script which downloads blobs from Azure Storage with PowerShell:

```
ForEach ($blob in $topBlobs) {
    Write-Output "Downloading $blob.Name..."

    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob.Name `
      -Container $ContainerName `
      -Destination $officeFolder `
      -Context $ctx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Confirm:$false

    Write-Output "Done."
}
```

How can I force it to answer NO no matter what? If I run it as is now from command line (.cmd file on Windows) it asks for a confirmation!

Comment: Side note, you can't expand object properties like you are in line 2. Update it to `"Downloading $($blob.Name)..."` for better results. For better 'current status' messages check out `write-progress`!

Comment: good point! thanks! fixed

Comment: I guess I don't understand the purpose.  This seems a little bit like asking to call `Get-Content` except you don't want the file content to be read.  Well, what are you calling it for then?  What behavior do you get with a `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` that doesn't download anything that `Get-AzureStorageBlob` doesn't supply?  Can't you `Test-Path` on the output file to test if it exists before calling the command?

Comment: I have a blob container - image warehouse. the images keep getting stored in it. so I need a script to see/download the latest N images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-Confirm` switch is set to false by default so you omit it. You may see the confirmation dialog due to an existing file. You can bypass it by adding the `-force` switch.

---

Okay, So since you don't want to overwrite the files you could do something like this:

```
$existingFiles = Get-childitem $officeFolder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach ($blob in ($topBlobs | Where-Object Name -NotIn $existingFiles)) {

    Write-Output "Downloading $blob.Name..."

    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob.Name `
      -Container $ContainerName `
      -Destination $officeFolder `
      -Context $ctx 

    Write-Output "Done."
}
```

Comment: now it just overwrites the files, so it answers Yes. I need NO

Comment: now this

$existingFiles = Get-Content $officeFolder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

gives access denied... whichever folder I use

Comment: Sorry, meant get-childitem

Answer (score 0):

The confirm flag is what you are looking for [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-5.3.0)

It defaults to false, but you are probably confusing it by over

Comment: fix the link please